# RealmObject not saving data

Tags: android, realm

I am saving data to a `RealmObject` then adding it to my `Realm`. After leaving the activity and returning the `RealmObject` is retrieved and the `EditText` are loaded with the appropriate data. All the `EditText` but one, Company Address, are loading correctly and I can't figure out why when all save and loading information is the same. Any ideas?

Activity

```
public class NewLocation extends ActionBarActivity {

    public EditText editCoName;
    public EditText editCoAddress;
    public EditText editCoContact;
    public EditText editSqFt;
    public EditText editTaxed;
    public EditText editConcerns;
    private Realm realm;
    public CompanyInfo companyInfo;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_location);

        findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SaveInfo();
                Intent i = new Intent(NewLocation.this, RoomList.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        editCoName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CoName);
        editCoAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CoAddress);
        editCoContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CoContact);
        editSqFt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SqFt);
        editTaxed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Taxed);
        editConcerns = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Concerns);

        //initialize realm and make CompanyInfo object if there is not already one
        realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
        CompanyInfo result = realm.where(CompanyInfo.class).findFirst();
        if (result == null){
            realm.beginTransaction();
            companyInfo = realm.createObject(CompanyInfo.class);
            companyInfo.setName(editCoName.getText().toString());
            companyInfo.setAddress(editCoAddress.getText().toString());
            companyInfo.setContact(editCoContact.getText().toString());
            companyInfo.setTaxed(editTaxed.getText().toString());
            companyInfo.setSqFt(editSqFt.getText().toString());
            companyInfo.setConcerns(editConcerns.getText().toString());
            realm.commitTransaction();
        }
        else {
            editCoName.setText(result.getName());
            editCoAddress.setText(result.getAddress());
            editCoContact.setText(result.getContact());
            editTaxed.setText(result.getTaxed());
            editSqFt.setText(result.getSqFt());
            editConcerns.setText(result.getConcerns());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LoadInfo();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SaveInfo();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
    }

    public void SaveInfo() {
        //save all info from the page

        companyInfo = realm.where(CompanyInfo.class).findFirst();

        realm.beginTransaction();
        companyInfo.setName(editCoName.getText().toString());
        companyInfo.setAddress(editCoAddress.getText().toString());
        companyInfo.setContact(editCoContact.getText().toString());
        companyInfo.setTaxed(editTaxed.getText().toString());
        companyInfo.setSqFt(editSqFt.getText().toString());
        companyInfo.setConcerns(editConcerns.getText().toString());
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(companyInfo);
        realm.commitTransaction();


    }

    public void LoadInfo() {
        //load info fom the CompanyInfo and put it into EditTexts

        companyInfo = realm.where(CompanyInfo.class).findFirst();
        if (companyInfo != null) {
            editCoName.setText(companyInfo.getName());
            editCoAddress.setText(companyInfo.getAddress());
            editCoContact.setText(companyInfo.getContact());
            editTaxed.setText(companyInfo.getTaxed());
            editSqFt.setText(companyInfo.getSqFt());
            editConcerns.setText(companyInfo.getConcerns());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_location, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.home:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPage.class));
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

CompanyInfo class

```
public class CompanyInfo extends RealmObject{
    @PrimaryKey
    private String Name;
    @Ignore
    private String Address;
    private String Contact;
    private String sqFt;
    private String taxed;
    private String concerns;
    private RealmList<Rooms> rooms = new RealmList<>();

    public RealmList<Rooms> getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }

    public void setRooms(RealmList<Rooms> rooms) {
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return Contact;
    }

    public String getSqFt() {
        return sqFt;
    }

    public String getTaxed() {
        return taxed;
    }

    public String getConcerns() {
        return concerns;
    }

    public void setName(String coName) {
        this.Name = coName;
    }

    public void setAddress(String coAddress) {
        this.Address = coAddress;
    }

    public void setContact(String coContact) {
        this.Contact = coContact;
    }

    public void setSqFt(String sqFt) {
        this.sqFt = sqFt;
    }

    public void setTaxed(String taxed) {
        this.taxed = taxed;
    }

    public void setConcerns(String concerns) {
        this.concerns = concerns;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should probably remove the line `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(companyInfo);`. As `companyInfo` is a Realm object, the setters will change the object when you commit the transaction.

Comment: The address still isn't saving after removing the line

Comment: The `@Ignore` annotation in your model class `CompanyInfo` implies that the field is never stored in the Realm file. So any changes will not be saved.

Comment: Deleting `@Ignore` was what helped thank you so much

Comment: Great to hear that. Sorry to missed it the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `@Ignore` annotation on `CompanyInfo#Adresse`, remove it and Realm will save the adress.